# Addding Appium node to hub on Selenium Grid 4

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-grid

Hi guys we are using Selenium 4 , we are trying add a node to Selenium hub from different machine. We are having connection issue. When I am adding node on the same machine with hub I am having no issues. I am only getting issue when node and hub on different machines. I use toml and yaml files to start grid and connect the node as below.

TOML FILE:

```
[server]
port = 5556

[node]
detect-drivers = false

[relay]
url = "http://localhost:4733"
status-endpoint = "/status"
configs = [
    "1", "{\"platformName\": \"windows\", \"appium:automationName\": \"windows\"}"
]
```

YAML FILE :

```
server:
  port: 4733
  use-drivers:
    - appium-windows-driver
```

Here are my steps to do set up node

1. java -jar C:\seleniumgrid\selenium-server-4.10.0.jar hub
2. appium --config C:\seleniumgrid\appium1.yml
3. java -jar C:\seleniumgrid\selenium-server-4.10.0.jar node --config C:\seleniumgrid\node1.toml

Please advise what I am doing wrong. Based on the suggestion on the selenium ticket I opened (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12341 , I am getting confused about the part which says "  server section needs to have the information from the host where the Node runs." How do I add host information into server section.

Thanks